# Trainer Component Error in Tensorflow Extension

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-transform, tfx

it is my first time building a tfx pipeline after I went through the tutorials and trying to build one with my own dataset. I could use some advice on the transform code that I wrote, and understand better, I'd appreciate your time and thanks in advance.

I've done the ExampleGen, StatisticsGen, SchemaGen, ExampleValidator, Transform, and having error in Trainer components.

**ERROR:**

```
c:\lib\site-packages\tfx\orchestration\launcher\in_process_component_launcher.py in _run_executor(self, execution_id, input_dict, output_dict, exec_properties)
     65         executor_context)  # type: ignore
     66 
---> 67     executor.Do(input_dict, output_dict, exec_properties)

c:\lib\site-packages\tfx\components\trainer\executor.py in Do(self, input_dict, output_dict, exec_properties)
    317 
    318     fn_args = self._GetFnArgs(input_dict, output_dict, exec_properties)
--> 319     trainer_fn = self._GetFn(exec_properties, 'trainer_fn')
    320 
    321     schema = io_utils.parse_pbtxt_file(fn_args.schema_file, schema_pb2.Schema())

c:\lib\site-packages\tfx\components\trainer\executor.py in _GetFn(self, exec_properties, fn_name)
    128     if has_module_file:
    129       return import_utils.import_func_from_source(
--> 130           exec_properties['module_file'], fn_name)
    131 
    132     fn_path_split = exec_properties[fn_name].split('.')

c:\lib\site-packages\tfx\utils\import_utils.py in import_func_from_source(source_path, fn_name)
     66       user_module = types.ModuleType(loader.name)
     67       loader.exec_module(user_module)
---> 68       return getattr(user_module, fn_name)
     69 
     70   except IOError:

AttributeError: module 'user_module' has no attribute 'trainer_fn'
```

**CODE:**

```
def get_model(show_summary=True):

#one-hot categorical features
num_A = 4,
num_B = 3,
num_C = 2,
num_D = 8,
num_E = 12,
num_F = 4,
num_G = 16,
num_H = 26

input_A = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_A,), name="A_xf")
input_B = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_B,), name="B_xf")
input_C = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_C,), name="C_xf")
input_D = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_D,), name="D_xf")
input_E = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_E,), name="E_xf")
input_F = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_F,), name="F_xf")
input_G = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_G,), name="G_xf")
input_H = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_H,), name="H_xf")


fl = keras.Input(shape=(75,))
dense = layers.Dense(35, activation = "relu")
x = dense(fl)
x = layers.Dense(15, activation="relu")(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

_inputs = [input_A, input_B, input_C, input_D, input_E, input_F, input_G, input_H]


model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

if show_summary:
    model.summary()

return model
```

Comment: Please make your code [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the directions and comment by Jason, I've changed up the model part as tfx doesn't support the sequential model but the Keras functional API.

```
def get_model(show_summary=True):

#one-hot categorical features
num_A = 4,
num_B = 3,
num_C = 2,
num_D = 8,
num_E = 12,
num_F = 4,
num_G = 16,
num_H = 26

input_A = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_A,), name="A_xf")
input_B = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_B,), name="B_xf")
input_C = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_C,), name="C_xf")
input_D = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_D,), name="D_xf")
input_E = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_E,), name="E_xf")
input_F = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_F,), name="F_xf")
input_G = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_G,), name="G_xf")
input_H = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_H,), name="H_xf")

inputs_con = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([
input_A,
input_B,
input_C,
input_D,
input_E,
input_F,
input_G,
input_H])

dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation = 'relu')(inputs_con)
dense_2 = tf keras.layers.Dense(25, activation = "rely") (dense_1)
output = tf.keras.laters.Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid") (dense_2)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

_inputs = [
input_A,
input_B,
input_C,
input_D,
input_E,
input_F,
input_G,
input_H]

model = tf.keras.models.Model(_inputs, output)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss='binary_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

if show_summary:
    model.summary()

return model
```

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem and were able to solve it by migrating from the tf.keras sequential model api to the functional api. You can read about the different model apis [here](https://keras.io/api/models/). You'll notice in the tutorials that the wide and deep model is implemented as a functional api.

As an example, here is a sample of a keras model for the trainer component:

```
def _build_functional_test_model():
colname = 'feature_string_xf'
feature_columns = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column(colname, shape=_MAX_REQUEST_LEN, dtype=tf.dtypes.int64, default_value=0)]

input_layers = {
    colname: tf.keras.layers.Input(name=colname, shape=_MAX_REQUEST_LEN, dtype=tf.int64)
}

input_dense_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)(input_layers)

embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(_N_UNIQUE_WORDS,
                                      _N_EMBED,
                                      input_length=_MAX_REQUEST_LEN)(input_dense_layer)

embedding_dropout = tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout1D(_DROPOUT_EMBEDDING)(embedding)

conv_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(_N_CONV_1,
                                _K_CONV_1,
                                activation='linear',
                                activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(_REGULARIZE_L1_CONV))(
    embedding_dropout)
activation_1 = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(conv_1)
dropout_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(_DROPOUT_CONV_1)(activation_1)

conv_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(_N_CONV_1,
                                _K_CONV_2,
                                activation='linear',
                                activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(_REGULARIZE_L1_CONV))(dropout_1)
activation_2 = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(conv_2)
dropout_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(_DROPOUT_CONV_1)(activation_2)

conv_3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(_N_CONV_3,
                                _K_CONV_3,
                                activation='linear',
                                activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(_REGULARIZE_L1_CONV))(dropout_2)
activation_3 = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(conv_3)
dropout_3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(_DROPOUT_CONV_1)(activation_3)

conv_4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(_N_CONV_4,
                                _K_CONV_4,
                                activation='linear',
                                activity_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(_REGULARIZE_L1_CONV))(dropout_3)
activation_4 = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(conv_4)
dropout_4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(_DROPOUT_CONV_1)(activation_4)

max_pool_5 = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D()(dropout_4)

dense_6 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(_N_DENSE_1,
                                activation='linear',
                                # activity_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1(_REGULARIZE_L1_DENSE_1)
                                )(max_pool_5)
activation_6 = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(dense_6)
dropout_6 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(_REGULARIZE_L1_DENSE_1)(activation_6)

dense_7 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(_N_DENSE_2,
                                activation='linear',
                                # activity_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1(_REGULARIZE_L1_DENSE_1)
                                )(dropout_6)
activation_6 = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(dense_7)
dropout_7 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(_REGULARIZE_L1_DENSE_1)(activation_6)

output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dropout_7)

model = tf.keras.Model(input_layers, output)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=_OPTIMIZER, metrics=['accuracy'])

return model
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and point me in the right direction. I will change my code and give you a shout if I make it. Thanks, Jason.

Comment: Hi Jason, after changing the sequential model to use Keras functional API, I'm still getting the same error. Just more information for you, the data features are all categorical data, and I'm using One Hot encoding to transform the data. Please advice, and thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for your direction. After changed up to use keras model, the trainer works in the tfx pipelines. \

Comment: great to hear!!